# How to use regex for digit?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string  which  has digit and words I want to use regex  in java.

```
String  s="S.No.DistrictMarketPrice 1 Agra Achhnera NIL 2 Agra Agra 1450 3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri 8765 5 Agra Jagner NIL 6 Agra Jarar NIL 7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 9 Aligarh Atrauli 1298 10 Aligarh Chharra NIL";
```

I want to break this string. I want every string in new line which should start from only exact serino

How can I get this output

```
S.No  .District  Market                Price
1      Agra      Achhnera              NIL
2      Agra      Agra                 1450
3      Agra      Fatehabad             NIL
4      Agra      Fatehpur Sikri       8765
```

Comment: my mistaken i posted wrong question

Comment: i updated my question can any one give me ans according to them please

Comment: Just use this - `line.replaceAll("\\s(\\d+\\s[A-Z])", "\n$1");` to break only at the S.NO.

Comment: Your latest update should be a question on it's own. As far as your original question, you should go ahead accept one of the answers.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung ur ans worked for me

Comment: That was only a comment. The actual answer was by @assylias.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace each number by a new line + the number:

```
String multiline = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "\n$1");
```

- `(\\d+)` captures the number
- `$1` refers to the captured number

Comment: What `$1` do? Value of digit?

Comment: @Karna Capture group.

Answer (score 2):

Replace any instance of one or more digits with the system line separator followed by the matched digit(s).

As such:

```
String  s = "S.No.DistrictMarketPrice 1 Agra Achhnera NIL 2 Agra Agra NIL 3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL 5 Agra Jagner NIL 6 Agra Jarar NIL 7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL 10 Aligarh Chharra NIL";

System.out.println(
    s.replaceAll("\\d+", System.getProperty("line.separator") + "$0")
);
```

**Output**

```
S.No.DistrictMarketPrice 
1 Agra Achhnera NIL 
2 Agra Agra NIL 
3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 
4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL 
5 Agra Jagner NIL 
6 Agra Jarar NIL 
7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 
8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 
9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL 
10 Aligarh Chharra NIL
```

Comment: @user3456343 What do you mean by serino?

Comment: @user3456343 You would have to parse over the first output and replace whitespace with tab for the digit starting lines. For the header, you'd have to chunk manually as there's no automatic criterium.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
String []splits = s.split("(?<!\\d)(?=\\d+)");
```

splits contains lines per index:

```
S.No.DistrictMarketPrice 
1 Agra Achhnera NIL 
2 Agra Agra NIL 
3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 
4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL 
5 Agra Jagner NIL 
6 Agra Jarar NIL 
7 Agra Khairagarh NIL 
8 Agra Shamshabad NIL 
9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL 
10 Aligarh Chharra NIL
```

Comment: @user3456343 it can be `s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)(?=\\d+)", "\n");` if you want the same string to be converted.

Comment: thax for replay  dear but i want this in same line "2 Agra Agra 1450"